# Elasticsearch mapping not updated after inserting new document via tire (mongoid4, rails4)

Tags: mongoid, elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-4, tire

Recently I've encountered a strange behaviour regarding elasticsearch with rails4/mongoid4/tire. I managed to do a temporary fix, but I want to know if there is a cleaner solution and where exactly the problem lies (is it an elasticsearch issue?)

Relevant part of my Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem "mongoid", github: 'mongoid/mongoid'
gem 'tire'
```

Elasticsearch version:

```
  "version" : {
    "number" : "0.90.2",
    "snapshot_build" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.3.1"
  }
```

My model:

relevant part of my model consists of Ad class:

```
class Ad
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, type: String
  [... other stuff...]
end
```

and Ad subclasses, one of which is:

```
class AdInAutomotiveAutomobile < Ad
  field :make
  field :model
  field :body_type
  tire.index_name 'ads'
  [... other stuff ...]
end
```

using inheritance doesn't seem to have any importance, but I'm mentioning it just for the record

### The problem

Inserting new Ad doesn't update the mapping of 'ads' index

```
{
  "ads": {
    "ad_in_automotive_automobile": {
      "properties": {
        "$oid": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Logs output, trimmed down:

```
# 2013-08-02 15:40:58:387 [ad_in_automotive_automobile/51fbb6b26f87e9ab1d000001] ("ads")
#
curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/ads/ad_in_automotive_automobile/51fbb6b26f87e9ab1d000001" -d '{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "51fbb6b26f87e9ab1d000001"
  },
  "active": null,
  "body_type": "hatchback",
  "c_at": "2013-08-02T13:40:57.647Z",
  "category_id": {
    "$oid": "51e8020c6f87e9b8e0000001"
  },
  "color": null,
  "description": null,
  "engine_displacement": null,
  "expire_at": null,
  "fuel_type": null,
  "locale": null,
  "make": "ford",
  "meta": {},
  "mileage": null,
  "model": "focus",
  "power": null,
  "price": null,
  "title": "foo",
  "transmission": null,
  "u_at": "2013-08-02T13:40:57.647Z",
  "year": null,
  "category_slug": "automotive-automobile"
}'

# 2013-08-02 15:40:58:388 [201]
#
# 
{
  "ok": true,
  "_index": "ads",
  "_type": "ad_in_automotive_automobile",
  "_id": "51fbb6b26f87e9ab1d000001",
  "_version": 1
}
```

### The solution

Somehow, this:

```
"_id":{"$oid":"51fbb6b26f87e9ab1d000001"}
```

is stopping elasticsearch from updating the mapping
So I've 'fixed' this in `#to_indexed_json` method:

```
  def to_indexed_json
    to_json(methods: [:category_slug]).gsub( /\{\"\$oid\"\:(\".{24}\")\}/ ) { $1 }
  end
```

Which results in:

```
# 2013-08-02 15:50:08:689 [ad_in_automotive_automobile/51fbb8fb6f87e9ab1d000002] ("ads")
#
curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/ads/ad_in_automotive_automobile/51fbb8fb6f87e9ab1d000002" -d '{
  "_id": "51fbb8fb6f87e9ab1d000002",
  "active": null,
  "body_type": "hatchback",
  "c_at": "2013-08-02T13:50:08.593Z",
  "category_id": "51e8020c6f87e9b8e0000001",
  "color": null,
  "description": null,
  "engine_displacement": null,
  "expire_at": null,
  "fuel_type": null,
  "locale": null,
  "make": "ford",
  "meta": {},
  "mileage": null,
  "model": "focus",
  "power": null,
  "price": null,
  "title": "foo",
  "transmission": null,
  "u_at": "2013-08-02T13:50:08.593Z",
  "year": null,
  "category_slug": "automotive-automobile"
}'

# 2013-08-02 15:50:08:690 [201]
#
# 
{
  "ok": true,
  "_index": "ads",
  "_type": "ad_in_automotive_automobile",
  "_id": "51fbb8fb6f87e9ab1d000002",
  "_version": 1
}
```

And now the mapping is OK:

```
{
  "ads": {
    "ad_in_automotive_automobile": {
      "properties": {
        "$oid": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "body_type": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "c_at": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "dateOptionalTime"
        },
        "category_id": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "category_slug": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "make": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "meta": {
          "type": "object"
        },
        "model": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "title": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "u_at": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "dateOptionalTime"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### The question(s), once again

Why does it happen?

What part of stack is responsible for that?

Can it be fixed in cleaner way?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, it made me bang my head at the wall for a while, until I looked at the elastic search logs, since tire was silently failing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the guy from the comment, it looks like this is fixed in tire HEAD, look at this issue https://github.com/karmi/tire/issues/775. I havent verified the fix since I monkey patched the class. This is the patch in case you want to go that way:

```
require "tire"
module Tire
  class Index
    def get_id_from_document(document)
     case
        when document.is_a?(Hash)
          document[:_id] || document['_id'] || document[:id] || document['id']
        when document.respond_to?(:id) && document.id != document.object_id
          document.id.to_s   # was document.id.as_json
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I am familiar with this issue, I'm using this initializer, however it didn't work for me - sanitizing json in #to_indexed_json does.